# Python "join" on both sides of strings?

Tags: python, string, list

```
l = ['1','2','3']
goal = ['<li>1</li>','<li>2</li>']
```

How can I get `goal` from `l`?

I'm playing with list comprehensions but it's messy!

Comment: Did you mean to exclude your last item (3) in the list `l` from your `goal`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try string formatting and list comprehension, like so.

```
goal = ['<li>{0}</li>'.format(x) for x in l]
```

Comment: Lovely, thanks. Although I used the original you posted.. ".format" seems superfluous.

Answer (score 1):

Two options using `str.format()`:

```
goal = map('<li>{0}</li>'.format, l)
```

... or...

```
goal = ['<li>{0}</li>'.format(x) for x in l]
```

Note that on Python 3.x `map()` will return an iterator instead of a list, so if you want a list you would need to use `list(map(...))`.

Answer (score 0):

With `string.format` method

```
goal = ['<li>{0}</li>'.format(sym)  for sym in l]
```